# Action bar in Android like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-actionbar, whatsapp

How does whatsapp implement its action bar?The latest updated version contains action bar which works perfect on android 2.2 and android 4.1 without any differences.
Any ideas how they've achieved backward compatibility? 
The back button works on android 2.2 which i could not get working by any means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Androlyzer](https://www.androlyzer.com/app/com.whatsapp/43847/2cad0baf559b6aab1db627bc647e6e0472320131), Whatsapp uses [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for their Action Bar, which allows them to have a consistent Action Bar on all Android 2.1+ devices